# Easier way to add multiple list items?

Tags: python

Is there an easier way to sum together items from a list than the code I've written below? I'm new to this and this seems somewhat unwieldy.

```
n = [3,5,7]
o = [4,10,8]
p = [4,10,5]

lists = [n, o, p]

def sumList(x):
    return sum(x)


def listAdder(y):
    count = 0
    for item in y:
        count += sumList(item)
    return count

print listAdder(lists)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like:

```
from itertools import chain

n = [3,5,7]
o = [4,10,8]
p = [4,10,5]

print sum(chain(n, o, p))
# 56
```

This avoids creating an un-necessary list of items, since you pass them to `chain` directly...

Answer (score 7):

You can do it in a single line, `listAdder()` is the same as calling `sum()`:

```
sum(sum(x) for x in lists)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also avoid the list of lists and just sum directly:

`sum(n+o+p)`

Comment: Of course, this creates several lists for naught. By coping all elements from all lists, some of them multiple times too.

Answer (score 1):

As short as it gets, not very efficient though

```
sum(sum(lists, []))
```